# ModelState.IsValid threw an exception of type System.IO.FileLoadException

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, testing, nunit

I have an .NET MVC application and I'm writing some unit test for it using NUnit.

This is the function I'm currently testing:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> Add(AddInstrumentViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var group = new FtpServerGroup
        {
            Disabled = true,
            FtpLastPullTime = DateTime.Now,
            FtpPullInterval = TimeSpan.Zero,
        };

        await db.CreateAsync(group, model.Address, model.Username, model.Password);

        // go back to card view
        var res = await db.GetAll();
        return RedirectToAction("Index", res);
    }

    return View(model);
}
```

this is the actual test:

```
[Test]
public async Task Test()
{
    var controller = new AutomaticTransferController(mockService.Object);

    var model = new AddInstrumentViewModel
    {
        Address = "124.124.124.124",
        Password = "123456",
        Username = "John Foo"
    };

    var res = await controller.Add(model);
}
```

Stepping with the debugger I noticed that as soon as I enter the .Add() method the line  `if (ModelState.IsValid)` throw an exception

> ModelState.IsValid threw an exception of type
>   System.IO.FileLoadException

In fact, it **threw** an exception without telling me when nor where

**EDIT**

This is the code for my InstrumentViewModel

```
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

    public class AddInstrumentViewModel
    {
        [Display(Name = "IP Address or Domain Name")]
        [Required]
        [RegularExpression(@"^(?:[0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}$")]
        public string Address { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "FTP Username")]
        [Required]
        public string Username { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "FTP Password")]
        [Required]
        public string Password { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: provide the code for AddInstrumentViewModel

Comment: What version of .net are you using. I am unable to reproduce the error. It runs to completion when I recreate a minimal version of your example. Also show how the mock service is setup

Comment: `FileLoadException` often gives this message: `Could not load file or assembly ...`. Check further error details, inner exceptions and possible missing references too.

Comment: @Nkosi I'm using .NET 1.0.0

Comment: @Fran I added the code for InstrumentViewModel

Comment: @GianlucaGhettini do you mean `asp.net-core 1.0` I highly doubt anyone still uses .net 1.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem. Just update & consolidate nuget packages. I'm not sure which exactly:)